# How to use wordpress plugin functions on my "home" page?

Tags: plugins, template-tags

The problem I am facing right now is, that I can't use functions provided by wordpress plugins on my "Home" page.

To be precise: I use wordpress together with the wp-e-commerce plugin, which has no real documentation. I had a template with some js-written checkout script which I need to replace with wp-e-commerce.

The frontpage showed a featured product and some jcarousel to show other products. The only thing I'd need to change are the functions, f.e. `the_title()` -> `wpsc_the_product_title()`.

Comment: Close-voted as *too localized*. This is a *Plugin-specific* support question, that should be directed to the Plugin developer.

Answer (score 1):

wp e-commerce has a few shortcodes for displaying products, you may be able to use one of these:

display products set as "featured":

```
[homepage_products]
```

show a whole category:

```
[wpsc_category=1]
```

the products are stored as a custom post type named "wpsc-product", so you could also just use all of  the built in WordPress functions for querying and displaying posts, along with the wp e-commerce function for displaying the add to cart controls:

```
<?php echo wpsc_add_to_cart_button(1); ?>
```